# seo url not displaying in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, seo

I'm busy creating a site that makes use of seo urls. I have a table that has the seo data and it references my menu table.

This is my helper function

```
function getSeo($menu_id)
{
$seo = DB::table('seo')->where('menu_id', '=', $menu_id)->get();

if(empty($seo)){
    return 'page/'. $menu_id;


}

if(!empty($seo[0]->url)){

    return 'page/'. $menu_id;

}

return $seo[0]->url;
}
```

My master.blade.php

```
@foreach($menus as $menu)

    <li>
        {{ HTML::link(getSeo($menu->id), $menu->title) }}
    </li>
@endforeach
```

If I remove

```
  return 'page/'. $menu_id;
```

from

```
if(!empty($seo[0]->url)){

    return 'page/'. $menu_id;
}
```

then it shows up in the bottom section where you can see the url if you hover of the link, but if you click on the link that you get a route error.

But if I do this:

```
if(!empty($seo[0]->url)){
    $menu_id = $seo[0]->url;
    return 'page/'. $menu_id;
}
```

then it works but my content doesn't show up when I click on the link.

If you need any information please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be in your 2nd if statement.

```
if(!empty($seo[0]->url)){
    return 'page/'. $menu_id;
}
```

You are basically saying "if url is **not** empty, return page/menu_id".

The next line returns the `$seo[0]->url` only if it's empty.

Your if statement should rather be:

```
if(empty($seo[0]->url)){
    return 'page/'. $menu_id;
}
```